# How can I get the distinct items of the following data structure in C# / LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have the following objects:

```
public class Agency  
{   
    public int ID; 
    public IEnumerable<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits;  
}  

public class BusinessUnit
{
    public int ID;  
    public decimal AmountSpent;
    public IEnumerable<Client> Clients;
}

public class Client
{
    public int ID;  
    public decimal AmountSpent;
}
```

Now, I have a IEnumerable`<Agency`> which contains several agencies, these agencies contain several BusinessUnits, and those BusinessUnits contain several clients.

It might look something like:

> Agency1
>   ++BusinessUnit1  - $20
>   ++++Client1  - $10
>   ++++Client2  - $10
>
> Agency2
>   ++BusinessUnit2  - $20
>   ++++Client1  - $20
>
> Agency3
>   ++BusinessUnit1  - $10
>   ++++Client5  - $5
>   ++++Client6  - $5
>   ++BusinessUnit2  - $25
>   ++++Client1 - $25

Now, what I'm looking to do, is create a list of BusinessUnits and Clients, but for all agencies, without duplicates.

So, I'm looking to turn that list of Agencies into:

> All Agencies
>   ++BusinessUnit1  - $30
>   ++++Client1  - $10
>   ++++Client2  - $10
>   ++++Client5 - $5
>   ++++Client6 - $5
>
> ++BusinessUnit2  - $45
>   ++++Client1  - $20
>   ++++Client1 - $25

Where I simply have a list of unique BusinessUnits (with their correct AmountSpent total across all instances of that particular BusinessUnit), and with a list of unique clients under them, with the correct AmountSpent total for each instances of that particular client under that business unit.

Is it possible with LINQ that I can I query my IEnumerable`<Agency`> Agencies list to return my distinct list of BusinessUnit/Client combinations with the correct sums?

Comment: @Alan, correct.  Agency.BusinessUnits only has one of each BusinessUnitID

Comment: @Alan, however, you might have Client1 in two different places among 2 different BusinessUnits.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, methinks (untested):

```
var res = agencies.SelectMany(a => a.BusinessUnits)
                  .GroupBy(b => b.ID)
                  .Select(b => new BusinessUnit { 
                     ID = b.Key, 
                     AmountSpent = c.Sum(b2 => b2.AmountSpent),
                     Clients = b.SelectMany(b2 => b2.Clients)
                                .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
                                .Select(c => new Client { 
                                   ID = c.Key, 
                                   AmountSpent = c.Sum(c2 => c2.AmountSpent) 
                                 })
                   });
```

<strike>There may be a way to optimize away the anonymous class creation.  I'll leave that up to you.</strike>  Assuming that BusinessUnit.AmountSpent is correct we probably don't need to sum up the Client's AmountSpent.

---

On a second read it looks like you might not want to collapse Clients underneath Business Units but keep each instance, in that case you can get rid of b.SelectMany(b2 => b2.Clients) and everything that follows and just use b.Clients.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groupings =
    from agency in agencies
    from businessUnit in agency.BusinessUnits
    from client in businessUnit.Clients
    group client by businessUnit.ID into clients
    select clients;

var businessUnits =
    from grouping in groupings
    select new
    {
        ID = grouping.Key,
        AmountSpent = grouping.Sum(client => client.AmountSpent),
        Clients = grouping
    };

Console.WriteLine("All Agencies");

foreach (var businessUnit in businessUnits)
{
    Console.WriteLine("++BusinessUnit{0} - ${1}",
                      businessUnit.ID,
                      businessUnit.AmountSpent);

    foreach (var client in businessUnit.Clients)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("++++Client{0} - ${1}", client.ID, client.AmountSpent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joe Chung, very nice!  If BusinessUnit had a "Name" property, how would I include that in the result?  Here I see you are accessing "key", but since you can only do that for one, how would it change if you also needed a string called "Name" from the BusinessUnit and Client?

Comment: In that case you can create a new compound key: group client by new { businessUnit.ID, businessUnit.Name } into clients